# Tensorflow Actor Critic fails locally in Pycharm with OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError

Tags: python, tensorflow

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/reinforcement_learning/actor_critic

I'm trying to copy and run this code locally (outside colab where it runs fine) and modify it, but when I run (even the original) I get an error.

I can't figure out how to fix (or what causes) the following error.

```
for t in tf.range(max_steps):
    state = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)
    softmax_action, value = model(state)
    action = tf.random.categorical(softmax_action, 1)[0,0]
```

> File "", line 89, in run_episode
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError:
> Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did
> convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an
> unsupported feature.

Likewise, if I comment out the loop so it runs only one time (setting t=0) I still have another loop inside get_returns() producing the same error.

> File "", line 124, in get_returns
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError:
> Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did
> convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an
> unsupported feature.

If it matters, I'm on a macOS with M1 processor. Since it works in collab I'm wondering if that might have something to do with it?

```
tensorflow-macos==2.11.0
tensorflow-metal==0.7.1
```

EDIT (in case the link breaks)
Here is more code (minimal)

```
def run_episode(state, model, max_steps):
    action_probs = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    values = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    rewards = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    initial_state_shape = state.shape

    for t in tf.range(max_steps):
        state = tf.expand_dims(state, 0)
        softmax_action, value = model(state)
        action = tf.random.categorical(softmax_action, 1)[0,0]
        # ... more code below here...

@tf.function
def train_step(init_state, model, gamma, max_steps):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        action_probs, values, rewards = run_episode(init_state, model, max_steps)
        returns = get_returns(rewards, gamma, True)

        loss = custom_loss(action_probs, values, returns)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

        episode_reward = tf.math.reduce_sum(rewards)

        return episode_reward


t = tqdm.trange(num_episodes)
for i in t:
    state, info = env.reset()  # comment out this is for testing
    state = tf.constant(state, dtype=tf.float32)


    reward = train_step(state, model, gamma, max_steps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally figured out the problem. Turns out it was more closely related to how I had run the program (in Pycharm)

There are two possible resolutions.

The first is to put all my function definitions in a secondary .py file, import that file, and then run the code interactively (in pycharm on Mac this is done by selecting all your code and then using `Option + Shift + E`

Or by putting by entry code (in this case the final for loop that calls `train_step()` inside the following code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #  put the outer run loop here
```

Apparently I didn't read/understand the full error at first which was

> WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <function
> train_step at 0x16f2dc8b0> and will run it as-is. Cause: Unable to
> locate the source code of <function train_step at 0x16f2dc8b0>. Note
> that functions defined in certain environments, like the interactive
> Python shell, do not expose their source code. If that is the case,
> you should define them in a .py source file. If you are certain the
> code is graph-compatible, wrap the call using
> @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert. Original error: could not
> get source code To silence this warning, decorate the function with
> @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert   0%|          | 0/10000
> [00:00<?, ?it/s] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/code.py",
> line 90, in runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 240, in    File
> "/Path/To/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py",
> line 153, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None   File "", line 191, in train_step   File "", line 100, in run_episode
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError:
> Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did
> convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an
> unsupported feature.

I'm so used to jumping to the last line I missed the first few about using a .py file in interactive mode. I'll update the question title to better reflect what the true issue was.